# Any faces this kind of error in 32-bit machine?

Tags: mongodb

I have been using Mongo-db from one month ago i am getting the error as follows "MapViewOfFile failed /data/db/sgserver.4 errno:0 The operation completed successfully. 0".
If i check in the DB path c:/data/db the size not exceeded 2GB.I am using windows2003serverR2...Anyone faced same Issue share your experience.......

Advance Thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What size is the /data/db? This error is most likely from Mongo trying to allocate a new database file and that new file would push the size of the db past 2GB. MongoDB allocates database files in fairly large chunks so if you are anywhere near 2GB this could be the problem.

Comment: Hi,James Thanks for your kind Information..The /data/db size is "1.45GB" but i got the mentioned error message in mongod process..

Comment: Yeah - the next db file would cause you to go over the 2GB mark as @Gates VP said.

Answer (score 1):

Default file sizes for MongoDB

```
.ns =>  16MB
.0 =>   64 MB
.1 =>  128 MB
.2 =>  256 MB
.3 =>  512 MB
.4 => 1024 MB
```

Add that up and you're just under 2GB. So if you've filled the .4 file, then you won't be able to allocate any more space. (the `.5` file will be 2GB)

If you log into Mongo and do a `db.stats()`, how much space are you using? That should tell you how close you are to the limit.